# view log file effectively

Tags: logging

I searched logviewer and still not get right one!

My idea is:

1. Open a log file with log mode, then screen split with 3 window: 1 for orignal log file, the second one for filter keyword lines (regex support). the third one is all output line of the filter output.
2. If cursor move in filter output line, the main window will scroll to that line and hightlight the keyword.
3. If user change the second window keywords, the filter output window update as well.

Any exist package has similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but most of search related functions support similar behaviors. They list filtered result, and you can jump to any point you want from it. You don't really need a special mode to open your log file, just use these search function in your log file buffer.

Here are some I know:

`occur`: built-in search buffer function. (check `multi-occur` if you want to search multiple buffer)

`ag.el`: mode for "the silver searcher"

`swiper`: isearch with an overview